# Does anyone know why after I updated my android phone, that it doesn't unlock?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, ota-update, password, pattern-lock

I literally just updated my phone (I have a BLU X2 if that helps) to the new Android thing last night and my phone shuts down whenever I have any new updates. But I can't seem to unlock my phone this time. Like my password isn't working once I turn it back on and I've also tried all my old passwords and none of them work D:

Answer (score -2):

BLU pushed a bad update. Just google for BLU OTA lock. Looks like a factory reset is the only solution for now.